# Passing an extra parameter to ListItem onMouseOver handler

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, material-ui, flowtype

I have a material-ui `ListItem` within my React code base which looks like this

```
   <ListItem button key={currIndex} onMouseOver={handleOnMouseClickOnListItem}>
```

My handler looks like this (Note: I am using Flow typing).

```
  const handleOnMouseClickOnListItem: Event => void = (event: Event) => {
  }
```

I want to be able to pass `currIndex` as a parameter to my `handleOnMouseClickOnListItem`
alongside the existing `event`

I've tried the following but to no avail and I get the following error

**Cannot assign function to `handleOnMouseClickOnListItem` because function requires another argument from function type**

```
   <ListItem button key={currIndex} onMouseOver={handleOnMouseClickOnListItem(currIndex)}>
```

```
  const handleOnMouseClickOnListItem: Event => void = (event: Event, currIndex: number) => {
      console.log(currIndex);
  }
```

---

**Updated -Non-flow Solution (based on accepted answer below)**

[image: Edit amazing-rain-muor1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the handler, you'll have to either use a binding or an arrow function to bind your context to the event. An arrow function tends to me more readable but requires ES6. Here's an example:

`onMouseOver={(e) => handleOnMouseClickOnListItem(e, currIndex)}`

You have to also add the type for the new parameter in the parameters' type signature.

```
const handleOnMouseClickOnListItem: (Event, number) => void = (event: Event, currIndex: number) => {
          console.log(currIndex);
      }
```

Comment: Ah, well it looks like you also need to either use a binding or an arrow function on your handler like this:

    `onMouseOver={(e) => handleOnMouseClickOnListItem(e, currIndex)`

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. I did up a simplified CodeSandbox with your answer working here - https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-rain-muor1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark